# Rails and html - encoding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

in my template (index.html.erb) is no line for any code like utf-8 or anything.
so rails of course has a problem with that.

```
    Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.
```

so i tried to paste this into my html:
`# encoding: < meta charset=utf-8 />.`

did i write something wrong? or can i take any other code?

The answer from rails is: `unknown encoding name - <`

thanks for answering

Answer (score 4):

check if the file itself is saved as UTF-8.

This was my problem.

Using "e" as a texteditor or Notepad++ (or any other (windows) tool ) with wrong configuration may be the problem.

e (and i think Notepad++) was configured to save the files as "Windows DOS OEM (EP 437)".

I've changed this in the settings to UTF-8, saved alle files (withoth changes) and it works.

Comment: This was the problem for me, too.  I'm using Eclipse, which I just discovered to Cp1252.  I changed it to UTF-8 and saved the file again and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

in your application.rb file paste this line

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

or in your application.html.erb file paste the following line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The meta charset is for HTML. You need to specify the charset for ruby, you can do it by using a comment like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: yeah, sounds logical, thanks. 
But I can put the comment wherever I want (at the the top of the document like it's written or in the head), it still gives me the same error. Can't explain why...

Comment: Are you sure that you saved the template file in UTF8 encoding? What exactly did you write in the template file?

Answer (score 0):

Using Rubymine4, accidentally right clicked and didn't see what I had pressed... BANG! code = gone! Plus 1 error! I had reencoded the page to some crazy encoding. Just right click in page and -> save '[Your crazy Encoding here]' file in another encoding.

Rubymine, too easy! ;)

Answer (score 0):

That solved for me. It was my file that was not being saved as utf-8 after all.

https://superuser.com/questions/581553/sublime-text-2-encoding-utf-8