# ActionView::Template::Error (Your template was not saved as valid utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am writing my first Ruby On Rails program by following [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails)

Now I have created my first form as mentioned in section - **5.2 The first form**

My form looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8

<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Now when I try to load my page accessing URL - `http://localhost:3000/articles/new`, I get error as:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

The logs say this:

```
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Your template was not saved as valid utf-8. Please either specify utf-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by in
serting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.
```

So I already have the encoding set as my first line of my page, but still I am getting same error. Please tell me what is the mistake here?

**Update:**

I also tried setting the encoding using below line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But I am still getting same issue.

Comment: Check in your text editor, if encoding is set properly.

Comment: see this [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731071/rails-and-html-encoding-error)

Comment: @MarekLipka, I am using Notepad++. can you please tell me what setting should I make to work with Ruby On Rails.

Comment: @user3181365 It's encoding. I don't know where you can find it in Notepad++.

Comment: @MarekLipka, Thank you, I have set the encoding, then I saw special characters so I have created the file once again with same encoding rule. It is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, this is what I have done to fix the issue as per comments given by Marek Lipka.

Just modified the encoding in my editor to `UTF-8`. I am using Notepad++ in Windows 8. This is my form now:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to your text editor saves your code in some different encoding. Which text editor do you use?
Try to create the same in [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (very powerful text editor).

Or just try to find encoding settings in your text editor.